# analysis of vectors

Tags: vectors

A is a fixed point where that cross can freely rotate. How can I analyse the force F to two forces, one that is on the line from A to origin of F and the other perpendicular to that axis. I cannot find the angles! Let's say we know the distance from A to the center of the cross and the distance of origin of F to the center of the cross.

[image]

Comment: This is on the $3D$ plane right?

Comment: no, it's not 3D, all is coplanar, in one plane